# Trying to fadeIn .css ('background-image", __)

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-image, fadein

I'm trying to get a background image to swap between other images when divs are hovered over. What do I need to change to make the images fade between one another? Code looks like this:

```
  $('#mainUK').mouseenter(function(){
      $('.splash').css("background-image","url(Assets/Images/Splash/UK.jpg)");
  });

  $('#mainJapan').mouseenter(function(){
      $('.splash').css("background-image","url(Assets/Images/Splash/Japan.jpg)");
  });
etc..
```

CSS:

```
 .splash { 
      background-image: url(Assets/Images/Splash/UK.jpg);
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-position:center center; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      position:fixed;
    }
```

html:

```
<div class="splash_bg">
    <div class="splash">
      <div class="back_arrow"><h3>&larr;</h3></div>
      <div class="main_nav">
          <ul>
            <li class="main_headings"><div id="mainUK"><h3>The UK</h3></div></li>
            <li class="main_headings_sub"><a href="/England"><div id="mainEngland"><h3>England</h3></div></a></li>
            <li class="main_headings_sub"><a href="/Scotland"><div id="mainScotland"><h3>Scotland</h3></div></a></li>
            <li class="main_headings_sub"><a href="/Wales"><div id="mainWales"><h3>Wales</h3><div></a></li>
            <li class="main_headings"><a href="/Japan"><div id="mainJapan"><h3>Japan</h3></div></a></li>
            <li class="main_headings"><a href="/China"><div id="mainChina"><h3>China</h3></div></a></li>
            <li class="main_headings"><a href="/HK"><div id="mainHK"><h3>Hong Kong</h3><div></a></li>
            <li class="main_headings"><a href="/Malaysia"><div id="mainMalaysia"><h3>Malaysia</h3><div></a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

EDIT:

So I've solved it. Thanks to @demux/@luciferous as you pointed me in the right direction. If there's a better way to do this please feel free to let me know. Thank again.

html:

```
<div class="splash">
    <div class="splash_UK"></div>
    <div class="splash_Japan"></div>
    <div class="splash_China"></div>
    <div class="splash_HK"></div>
    <div class="splash_Malaysia"></div>
      <div class="back_arrow"><h3>&larr;</h3></div>
      <div class="main_nav">
          <ul>
            <li class="main_headings"><div id="mainUK"><h3>The UK</h3></div></li>
            <li class="main_headings_sub"><a href="/England"><div id="mainEngland"><h3>England</h3></div></a></li>
            <li class="main_headings_sub"><a href="/Scotland"><div id="mainScotland"><h3>Scotland</h3></div></a></li>
            <li class="main_headings_sub"><a href="/Wales"><div id="mainWales"><h3>Wales</h3><div></a></li>
            <li class="main_headings"><a href="/Japan"><div id="mainJapan"><h3>Japan</h3></div></a></li>
            <li class="main_headings"><a href="/China"><div id="mainChina"><h3>China</h3></div></a></li>
            <li class="main_headings"><a href="/HK"><div id="mainHK"><h3>Hong Kong</h3><div></a></li>
            <li class="main_headings"><a href="/Malaysia"><div id="mainMalaysia"><h3>Malaysia</h3><div></a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

CSS: (I've adjusted the z-index either side of the divs to 1 & 3 respectively.)

```
.splash_UK, .splash_Japan, .splash_China, .splash_HK, .splash_Malaysia{
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  opacity:0;
  z-index:2;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
  transition: opacity 200ms linear;
}

.splash_UK { 
  background-image: url(Assets/Images/Splash/UK.jpg);
}

.splash_Japan { 
  background-image: url(Assets/Images/Splash/Japan.jpg);
}

.splash_China { 
  background-image: url(Assets/Images/Splash/China.jpg);
}

.splash_HK { 
  background-image: url(Assets/Images/Splash/HK.jpg);
}

.splash_Malaysia { 
  background-image: url(Assets/Images/Splash/Malaysia.jpg);
}
```

JS:

```
 $('#mainJapan').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.splash_Japan').css('opacity', '1');
    $('.splash_UK,.splash_China,.splash_HK,.splash_Malaysia').css('opacity','0');
  });

  $('#mainUK').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.splash_UK').css('opacity', '1');
    $('.splash_Japan,.splash_China,.splash_HK,.splash_Malaysia').css('opacity','0');
  });

  $('#mainChina').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.splash_China').css('opacity', '1');
    $('.splash_Japan,.splash_UK,.splash_HK,.splash_Malaysia').css('opacity','0');
  });

  $('#mainHK').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.splash_HK').css('opacity', '1');
    $('.splash_Japan,.splash_China,.splash_UK,.splash_Malaysia').css('opacity','0');
  });

  $('#mainMalaysia').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.splash_Malaysia').css('opacity', '1');
    $('.splash_Japan,.splash_China,.splash_HK,.splash_UK').css('opacity','0');
  });
```

Comment: `background-image` property is not animatable in CSS.

Comment: You don't need and should absolutely not be using jQuery (or any javascript) for this. You can do this using pure css. Look for css transitions and css `:hover`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use multiple values  in the `background-image` property and toggle them on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var tar = document.getElementById('target');  
    var bgimage = $(tar).css('background-image');

    var bgimagearr = bgimage.split(',')

    $(tar).on('mouseenter', function() {

        $(this).css('background-image', bgimagearr[0])

    });

    $(tar).on('mouseleave', function() {

        $(this).css('background-image', bgimagearr[1])

    });
})
```

css would be something like

```
  #target{
        width:500px;
        height: 500px;
        background-image:url('./images/one.jpeg'),url('./images/two.jpeg');
    }
```

But it would i reckon it would be better to have two different elements altogether and achieve this easily, if your requirements are flexible,

Comment: This is much more elegant than my approach, but it doesn't seem to help with the fading in/out unless I'm missing something?

Comment: unfortunately since background-image is not in the list of animatable properties , we can't actually fadeIn the image :( https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties . 

But as i said, we should be able to cobble something up with two divs and get your requirement done !

Comment: maybe there's a way to animate the opacity value of a second separate div? Although I think I'd have to have a separate bg div for each list entry and then change the z-index too?

Answer (score 1):

#### A CSS only solution:

```css
.splash {
  font-family: sans-serif, verdana;
  position: relative;
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.splash-item-container {
  padding: 0;
}

.splash-item {
  margin: 2px 0;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.2);
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.splash-item a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.splash-item:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transition: background-color 1s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.splash-item-red:hover:before {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

.splash-item-green:hover:before {
  background-color: #ddffdd;
}

.splash-item-blue:hover:before {
  background-color: #ddddff;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash">
  <ul class="splash-item-container">
    <li class="splash-item splash-item-red"><a href="#">Red</a></li>
    <li class="splash-item splash-item-green"><a href="#">Green</a></li>
    <li class="splash-item splash-item-blue"><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### If you must use jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.main-nav li').hover(function() {
    $('.splash').removeClass('cats-bg sports-bg').addClass($(this).data('class'));
  });
});
```

```css
.splash {
  transition: background-image 1s;
}

.splash.cats-bg {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats/);
}

.splash.sports-bg {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="splash">
  <h3 class="black-arrow">&larr;</h3>

  <ul class="main-nav">
    <li data-class="cats-bg">Cats</li>
    <li data-class="sports-bg">Sports</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Elegant solution ! :)

Comment: This is great. I don't how I would implement this though, as I need a different div than the div which is hovered upon to change it's background-image.

Comment: @Scott, that's why the `.splash` div has `position: relative` and the child `li` being hovered over has content with `position: absolute`. In your specific case, the target element is also the parent of the element being hovered over, so you can implement the same solution. Only it won't be the actual background of the parent element changing, but rather another  element being overlayed.

Comment: @demux, ah i see what you've done now yes, but the hover state will only work while the mouse is over the div and I need it to stay (like how mouseenter works). Also your jQuery solution doesn't work for me - I think transition:background-image doesn't work on FF. Thank you for your response.